# Method that accepts a custom comparator and applies this to the list. Java

Tags: java, comparator

I want to sort the list using custom comparator in java.
For example:

```
public class Cart implements Comparator<Order>{

    private String cartId;
    private List<Order> productOrdersList;

    //is this the correct way to sort based on custom comparator?  
    public void sortOrders(Comparator<Order> order){
         //code to sort the list
         //Collections.sort(productOrdersList, order); 
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Order t, Order t1) {
        return t.getProduct().compareTo(t1.getProduct());
    }
```

I need to know how to sort the productOrdersList using sortOrders() method.
Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: You mean `this.productOrdersList.sort(order)`?

Comment: Will this make use of compare() method? I am a little bit confused about working of Comparator interface.

Comment: Yes. I guess anything that takes a `Comparable` means to call its `compare` method :-)

Comment: But why would ```sortOrders```take a ```Comparator<Order>``` parameter? It is an instance method of an instance of a class implementing Comparator<Order>. So using ```productOrdersList.sort(this)``` should suffice

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be mixing two still valid, but still different, approaches.

### Internal approach

```
public class Cart{

    private String cartId;
    private List<Order> productOrdersList;

    public void sortOrders(Comparator<Order> order){
         Collections.sort(productOrdersList, order); 
    }

}
```

In this case the sorting action is hidden by (or wrapped by) the method *sortOrders* and only the criteria of sorting cames from external.

### External approach

```
public class Cart implements Comparator<Order>{

    private String cartId;
    private List<Order> productOrdersList;
    private Comparator<Order> internal;

    public void setCriteria(Comparator<Order> comparator){
          this.internal = comparator;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Order t, Order t1) {
        return this.internal.compare(t,t1);
    }
}
```

In this case, again the criteria cames from external, but also the operation of sorting is called from outside the class with something like this:

`Collections.sort(cart.getProductOrdersList(), cart);`

So both approaches aren't wrong, but, onestly, I prefer the firstone because it seems less redundant.